# webview detect scrolling

Tags: android, webview, scroll

I have webview and other layout.
How to make when scrolling webview, the other layout makes invisible(Using View.GONE)

override touchlistener but Action.up can`t catch Action.up

how can implement it?

the point is detect when start or end scrolling

Comment: You are having any scroll view outside your webview... or any other scroll bar.

Comment: using webview`s default scroll

Comment: i solve this problem.
srr for dumm question
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4695318/1263908

Answer (score 2):

You can override onTouchEvent of your activity for ex:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     //Do something
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```